# Help identify this belt please?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

[image: picture of belt]

Can you help me identify this belt? It is 2mm wide and has a length of 133mm. It is a drive belt in a tape player from the 70s. It is exceptionally thin almost like a plastic film. It does not feel rubbery at all. Thank you!

Comment: Then go to belt manufacturers and check their listings

Comment: @SolarMike I keep running into companies that specialize in v-belts and much bigger solutions. If you could suggest any for these kind of micro belts I'd happily go through the listings!

Comment: Many plastics exist that do not feel rubbery at all.  Some are used to mimic LEATHER (strong hint there about older materials and their sources being biologically derived)... Find the seam in that belt, if there is one. Lack of one or how it is joined should clue you in.

Comment: It looks like a typical capstan drive belt off of 70's HiFi. TEAC perhaps. Thickness is generally about 0.5 mm so as to maintain tight drive speed consistency with very little variation in tension or bending moment.

Comment: Thanks @PhilSweet - that is an excellent lead and seems to fit my case. TEAC and Nakamichi seems to have used similar material. Not sure what it is but I'm a step closer!

Comment: Are you trying to put an old Nakamichi Dragon back together? Cool.